# Scala mutable list - insert element in the middle

Tags: scala, collections

How can I implement inserting element in the middle of DoubleLinkedList without coping it?
In general I want to find some element in the collection and then insert a new one after it.

There is method DoubleLinkedList.insert but I'm not quite sure how it works. In the documentation it's described this way:

> Insert linked list that at current position of this linked list

But what is the current position in the linked list? How can I set it?

I want to have O(1) insertion time.

Comment: You cannot have O(1), because you have to navigate to insertion point first, which is O(n) in linked list

Comment: Ok, you're right. I mean inserting in O(1) + O(n) for finding element of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first, you can't use `insert` to insert element, because it takes a `DoubleLinkedList` as parameter

> def insert(that: DoubleLinkedList[A]): Unit

just use `indexWhere` and `apply` methods, for example replacing 30 with 3:

`yourlist(yourlist.indexWhere(_ == 30)) = 3`

Comment: Wasn't the question about insertion, not replacement?

Answer (score 1):

To insert element in the middle of DoubleLinkedList you first to find your 'middle' and then make insertion:

```
val list = mutable.DoubleLinkedList(...)
list.next.next....insert(insertion)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `span` for separating the collection into the initial elements that hold a condition and those where the first item does not hold; e.g

```
val (l,r) = DoubleLinkedList(1,2,3,4,5).span(_ != 3)
l = DoubleLinkedList(1, 2)
r = DoubleLinkedList(3, 4, 5)
```

Then replace value `3` with `33` like this

```
l ++ DoubleLinkedList(33) ++ r.tail
```

**Note** In Scala 2.11.6 run the REPL with -deprecation to notice a deprecation warning such as

```
warning: object DoubleLinkedList in package mutable is deprecated:
Low-level linked lists are deprecated.
```